# How can I import only the first table from this URL?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2023-standard-pitching.shtml

I am trying to do some analysis on these baseball numbers and I need daily updates of the numbers. I was using the power query feature in excel, but apparently mac does not support Excel's auto update capability. Instead, I am trying to use importHTML() in google sheets.

=importHTML("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2023-standard-fielding.shtml", "table",1)

I have tried this. It worked when pulling other tables from the same sight, but in this case it is saying "Resource at URL contents exceeded maximum size". This table is the same size as the 3 other tables that were pulled successfully. I assume it has something to do with the second, lengthy table on the page.

I have tried using importHTML() in various ways with no luck. I thought this would pull the data just like it pulled 3 other tables from the site without trouble.

Comment: From the error message of `Resource at URL contents exceeded maximum size`, is using Google Apps Script included in your expected result? Or, are you required to use ` importHTML`?

Comment: You'd either a) need to write you're own function to parse it, or b) use something like Python to scrape the data